# How create a button which pause the thread which is inside the loop and another button which resumes

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable, synchronized

```
what is wrong with following code.
```

doing some stuff say words.lenght=1000 times
then suppose user want to take break in between
click pause button with id = bt this button pauses thread until   and user clicks resume with id= bt1

```
Runnable myRun = new Runnable(){
public void run(){

   for(int j =0 ;j<=words.length;j++){

   synchronized(this){
       try {

            wait(sleepTime);

            bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                            try {
                                wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                }});
            bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    notify();

                }
            });
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } }
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
           try {
                et.setText(words[i]);
                i++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }});
  }}};
```

Comment: Is there any error in the code or are asking about your approach.

Comment: @fahad i'm asking approach

Answer (score 0):

The code contains a mismatched closing curly bracket. Apart from that, it is badly formatted. Firstly, you should fix before asking people for advise on it. Secondly, I think the messed up formatting confused you, too, because some of this does not match with your description at all.

Comment: thanks for advice.. I'm new to android and java..if you have understood what i have asked then help me with some "code".